# CSS margin:0 auto not working on li>a

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I want a navigation bar with its elements (li>a) to be in the middle.
I achieved only the float left style.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font: 18px Inconsolata;
}
/* fdfdf */

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
ul>li:hover {
  background: #111;
}
li>a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <ul>
    <li><a class='active' href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you see I put in **ul>li>a {margin:0 auto;}**

Why doesn't it work?

Nav bar:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/h933o3jy/

You would need to make the `li` a *inline element*, and the parent of it should center it via `text-align:center`. like so:

```
#wrapper{
width:900px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
}

li {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

**udpate**

You will notice there's a space between those `li` items. To get rid of them, construct the HTML in a way that those tags are *glued* together. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/h933o3jy/1/ `</li><li>`

Comment: But one last thing, why doesn't it hover the whole background area of padding? I mean there is a little little space between the hover and the element before with class .active

Comment: Well that's because it's an inline-block. And thus, the space inbetween the '</li> <li>' tags is displayed. Just "glue" those tags togeter `</li><li>` and it will disappear https://jsfiddle.net/h933o3jy/1/

Answer (score 1):

margin on `a` is working but since li has `float:left` it is behaving as auto width.

If you are sure about having only 2 menu items you can remove the `float:left` from li and add float to only first li

```
ul li:first-child{
      float: left;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yj31h2gd/1/)**

Or add `width:50%` to `li`

```
li{
  float:left;
  width:50%
}
```

**[Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/yj31h2gd/3/)**